# Multiply EditText value with Spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner, converters

I´m currently working on a currency converter project for school. 
I have an array with currencies (USD,EUR etc) and one with values (6.54, 9.56 etc).

I have two spinners and one EditText and you choose From unit in one spinner and To unit in the other. Then it should consider the amount in editText and show the "live" result in textView. If you change spinners or editText the value in textview should update directly.

Let's say that the value inserted in editText is 10.0, and we want to convert it from USD to EUR, the calculation will look like this: 10.0*6.54/9.56=

But I can't figure out how to add the editText in to the calculation, now it only adds the value in spinner1 to the value in spinner2.

Here is strings.mxl

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">CurrencyConverter3</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">Dinner Time</string>
<string name="textView1Text">From:</string>
<string name="textView2Text">To:</string>
<string name="textView3Text">Amount:</string>
<string name="textView4Text">Amount:</string>
<string-array name="currency">
    <item >Choose currency</item>
    <item >AUD</item>
    <item >USD</item>
    <item >SEK</item>
    <item >EUR</item>
    <item >YEN</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="price">
    <item >0</item>
    <item >6.91</item>
    <item >6.54</item>
    <item >1.00</item>
    <item >9.56</item>
    <item >0.0837</item>
</string-array>
```

And here is mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.xxx.currencyconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String [] currency;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Spinner spin1, spin2;
    private EditText amount;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpTheSpinners();

    }


    private void setUpTheSpinners() {
        currency = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currency);
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currency);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new currencySelectedListener();
        spin1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spin1.setAdapter(adapter);
        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
        spin2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spin2.setAdapter(adapter);
        spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
    }

    private void calculateSum() {
        String [] price = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.price);
        int index1 = spin1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        int index2 = spin2.getSelectedItemPosition();
        double cost1 = Double.parseDouble( price[index1] );
        double cost2 = Double.parseDouble( price[index2] );
        double totalCost = cost1 + cost2;
        TextView totalCostText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        totalCostText.setText("" + totalCost);
    }



private class currencySelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        calculateSum();

    }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. get current edit text value with "edittext.getText().toString()"
2. parse the string as double
3. multiply with currency rate
4. parse output as string
5. set edit Text value to the output u get from 4th step

   ```
   private void convert() {
       String [] price = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.price);
       int index = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
       double curr_ratio = Double.parseDouble(price[index] );

       EditText et_value = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
       double value = Double.parseDouble(et_value.getText().toString());
       et_value.setText(String.valuOf(value*curr_ratio));
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but still not working. And when I use that solution, the app crashes

Comment: hard to anticipate wtihout u post the error log here

Comment: Seems that it's returning an empty string. Maybe someone can explain more details. Thank you